# How we find the PDE which the law of a stochastic process satisfies?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In the book of Villani titled *Hypocoercivity*, there is the following proposition.

> Let $\sigma \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^{n \times m})$ and $\xi \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^n)$, and let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a stochastic process solving the autonomous stochastic differential equation
> $$ dX_t = \sqrt{2}\sigma(X_t) dB_t + \xi(X_t)dt$$,
> where $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then the law $(\rho_t)_{t \ge 0}$ of $X_t$ satisfies the diffusion equation
> $$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot (D\nabla \rho - \xi \rho), \quad D := \rho^* \rho$$

Actually, the proof of this proposition says it is a classical consequence of Ito's formula, but I don't understand how they are related. Could you help me understand this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A useful pair of terms to look up is "backward Kolmogorov equation" and "forward Kolmogorov equation". The latter is what you actually wrote down. The term "Fokker-Planck equation" is synonymous with "forward Kolmogorov equation" but will get you into different literature.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I also found a book titled <Stochastic Processes and Applications> written by Grigorios A. Pavliotis, where there is a proof of it. I am not sure how I will make sure of it, but :)

Comment: @withgrace1040 Are you still reading "Hypocoercivity" written by Villani? I think we can form a small study group, maybe we can help each other